# Limiting characters/words in view - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am displaying recent comments on the home page of a blog application I am building in Ruby on Rails. I want to limit the number of characters that are displayed from the `body` column of the comments table.

I am assuming I can just add something to the end of the code for `<%=h comment.body %>` but I don't know what that would be yet as I am new to both Ruby and Rails.

Here is the code I have in the `/views/posts/index.html.erb` file:

```
<% Comment.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC', :limit => 5).each do |comment| -%>
    <p>
        <%=h comment.name %> commented on 
        <%= link_to h(comment.post.title), comment.post %><br/>
        <%=h comment.body %>
        <i> <%= time_ago_in_words(comment.created_at) %> ago</i>
    </p>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Try the [truncate](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001743) view helper

```
<%=h truncate(comment.body, :length => 80) %>
```

Comment: Just curious (not a Rails user): would this also work?

<%=h comment.body[0, 80]+"..." %>

Comment: That's pretty much what truncate does underneath, but it also checks the length to know if to add the '...' at the end

Comment: Just wanted to add that truncate is not multi-byte safe (ruby 1.8, rails 2.3.5, not sure about ruby 1.9). It truncates at the specified byte and if you have a unicode string the output will be shorter (less characters than the length specified). You could also end up with a broken character at the end. Of course, there's nothing to worry about if you use ASCII or any othern 8-bit character encoding.

Comment: What's the 'h' for in the beginning? or is that a typo?

Comment: @ProGrammar it's not a typo, since it's used multiple times; but I'd like to know if it's a built-in I should know about (like `j` is a shorthand for the `javascript` escape helper)

Answer (score 34):

I just found another way (if you don't want to add the "...")

```
<%= comment.body.first(80) %>
```

As said in the [RoR API for String](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html):

> first(limit = 1)
>
> Returns the first character. If a limit is supplied, returns a substring from the beginning of the string until it reaches the limit value. If the given limit is greater than or equal to the string length, returns self.

```
comment = "1234567890"

comment.first(5)
# => "12345"

comment.first(10)
# => "1234567890"

comment.first(15)
# => "1234567890"
```

Comment: Love this. Thanks. Cleaner and you don't need to include any Rails view helpers to use it.

Comment: attach .html_safe if html tags also included in text

Answer (score 8):

If you are using `rails 4.2` or above then you can use `truncate_words` method.

> For example:
>  
>   "In a world where everything is awesome".truncate_words(3)
>
> Output: "In a world..."

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `truncate` method if you want to limit the number of characters.

```
<%= "#{message.truncate(charcount)}" %>
```