# Ruby on Rails: How can i take/cut first 300 words or characters from a string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to take/cut first 300 words or characters from a string.

That means, I need a limited number of characters from a string, from the beginning.

Something like truncating.

Is there a function to do this?

Comment: Do you need 300 words or some number of characters? For characters, use http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D. For words, you'll need regex. Or is this on a Rails form or something?

Comment: @guru, please update your question's text to reflect characters, not words. The question is very misleading otherwise.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
str = "many words here words words words ..."
first_500_words = str.split(" ").first(500).join(" ")
first_500_chars = str[0..500]
```

Comment: `#first(500)` would be more elegant

Comment: @Tass, Can you post example with first(500) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23031956/3728916 - here is the example . and attach .html_safe if html tags also included in text

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the size of your text and performance needs, one option is `@text.split(/\s+/).slice(0,300).join(' ')`

Answer (score 3):

If you actually want to truncate on character level, which is advisable because different words differ in display length quite a bit, use:

```
def truncate_words(text, length = 300, end_string = ' …')
  words = text.split()
  words[0..(length-1)].join(' ') + (words.length > length ? end_string : '')
end
```

which I found here: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/804

If you're using Rails, you can also use `string.truncate` but it does not take into account word boundries.

Answer (score 0):

```
str = "this is really long string which I want to truncate..."

str.truncate 300, separator: " "
```

or if you prefer to youse brackets

```
str.truncate(300, separator: " ")
```

It's the most elegant solution of all above. As you mentioned in the topic, you use Rails so it will work. If you code in raw Ruby, you should write something like this:

```
str.split.first(300).join " "
```

The `split` method no need to take argument if you need to split the text by spaces.